# JQuery UI menubar dropdown issue

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menubar

When I have a menu item which contains a submenu, this submenu is shown inside the menu's div, screwing the css (hover over the *Services* tab):
http://jsfiddle.net/jYXnE/2/

There this part of the JS (that everyone seems to use) which bothers me when initializing the menubar plugin:

```
position: {
        within: $('#frame').add(window).first()
}
```

Since there is no `frame` id anywhere in the official examples, I guess it creates a div on-the-fly?

I compared my code to some other menubar jsFiddle and I can't find the issue to it, any help would be highled appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I had forgotten to link [menubar's CSS](http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/themes/base/jquery.ui.menubar.css). Everything is fine now.